# Java - Extending ArrayList, making methods private

Tags: java, arraylist, private, extend, extends

Im trying to extend an ArrayList to only make the add function available. Then Im creating an object of AlExtend, but I still have access to all the other methods besides add(). How can I create code that will allow objects of AlExtend to only use the add() function?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
public class AlExtend<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public AlExtend() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return super.add(e);
    }
 }

  public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          ALExtend<String> list = new ALExtend<String>();       
          list.add("fg");
          list.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can´t magicly make methods disapear by extending from another Object, that´s the principle of inheritance and why it is used...

Answer (score 5):

Inheritance won't give you the desired behavior. Use composition instead. Make an `ArrayList` instance a private member of your class, and only give access to its `add` method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class AlExtend<E> 
{
    private ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E> ();
    public AlExtend() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        return list.add(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaah! This is exactly what I was looking for. Almost to simple to figure out haha.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

In OOP, you cannot lessen the visibility of attributes/methods by inheritance. If you want to have an `List` of your own with only selected methods, you'd better use delegion instead of inheritance

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to rewrite a method with a lesser visibility of his superclass (or interface).

The only possibility is to create a **new class**, **not implementing** a `java.util.List` and **not extending** `ArrayList`, but only "*containing*" it. 
Expose only the method `add` in the new class, calling the corresponding method of the list.

```
public class OnlyAddList<E> {
    private List<E> originalList;

    public OnlyAddList(List<E> originalList) {
        this.originalList = originalList);
    }

    public void add(E element) {
        originalList.add(element);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Use the interface List instead of the concrete class ArrayList as parameter so your new class is more flexible. Using an interface instead of a concrete class is one of the good object oriented programming practice. See the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Answer (score 1):

User delegation instead of inheritance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AlExtend<E> {
    private ArrayList<E> list;

    public AlExtend() {
        list = new ArrayList<E>();
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        return list.add(e);
    }
}
```